# Исключение java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, исключения, коллекции

При попытке получить следующий элемент коллекции `int elem = itr.next();` выбрасывается исключение: `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

**Полный код:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class IteratorTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ListIterator<Integer> itr = list.listIterator();
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            list.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            int elem = itr.next();
            if(elem == 0) {
                itr.set(-1);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(list);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    list.add(sc.nextInt());
}
...
ListIterator<Integer> itr = list.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
```

Comment: Спасибо. А не поясните почему обязательно объявлять итератор до его использования в цикле?

Comment: @teoretik_eugene Потому что Вы создaете итератор, а потом начинаете менять список в цикле `for`. Итераторы этого не любят.

Comment: Спасибо! Все понятно

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @teoretik_eugene Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.